# Swift inout how to not copy back property when not changed, to not trigger objects setters

Tags: swift, inout

[according to the docs](https://%20https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID173)

> You write an in-out parameter by placing the inout keyword at the
>   start of its parameter definition. An in-out parameter has a value
>   that is passed in to the function, is modified by the function, and is
>   passed back out of the function to replace the original value.

But how to not copy back the result if it was not changed at all

I have a database parser
which assigns the `attr` only when it's value changes, however, with the behavior of inout, the `attr` that is passed in is always set (marking my database object dirty and changed :/ )

```
func importStringAttribute(_ json: JSON, _ key: String, _ attr: inout String?) {
    if !json[key].exists() {
        return
    }
    if let v = json[key].string, v != attr {
        attr = v
    }
}

// the myDBObject.someAttr is always set 
importStringAttribute(json, "someAttr", &myDBObject.someAttr)
```

**is there a way of modification, so the value is only set when the passed in attribute really changes?**

Comment: Does that method REALLY need an `inout`? Why? Why not make it "pure"?

And also what is your question really?

Comment: No; you cannot change inout's behavior here. You will need to modify the observer. (Whatever is watching `someAttr` needs to check that `value != oldValue`.)

Comment: A good general rule of thumb is: never use `inout`, in fact, very few scenarios merits the use of it. Mostly for performance, e.g. in implementations of block ciphers where same bytes allocated in memory are written to many thousand number of times.

Making your methods "pure" (by not using `inout`, and always returning output), also makes your code much easier to test, debug and reason about correctness :)

Comment: @Sajjon you cannot do this without inout, you would need to pass in a mutable object instead

Comment: @PeterLapisu You misunderstood me, I did of course not mean just removing `inout` statement from your function... but rather change your solution entirely, to only be using pure functions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `inout` works. You can't change that. `inout` literally means "copy the value into the function at the start and copy the value out of the function at the end." It doesn't do any analysis to decide whether the value was touched at runtime.

One solution is to check for trivial sets in the observer, for example:

```
var someAttr: String? {
    didSet {
        guard someAttr != oldValue else { return }
        ...
    }
}
```

As another approach, I suggest keypaths. Assuming that the database object is a reference type (class), I believe the following will do what you want:

```
func importStringAttribute(_ json: JSON, _ key: String, db: Database,
                           attr: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Database, String?>) {
    if !json[key].exists() {
        return
    }
    if let v = json[key].string, v != db[keyPath: attr] {
        db[keyPath: attr] = v
    }
}
```

The call is slightly longer because you need to pass the database itself:

```
importStringAttribute(json, "someAttr", db: myDBObject, attr: \.someAttr)
```

That could be made a little prettier by attaching the method to the database (though you still have to pass the database, just as self):

```
extension Database {
    func importStringAttribute(_ json: JSON, _ key: String,
                               _ attr: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Database, String?>) {
        if !json[key].exists() {
            return
        }
        if let v = json[key].string, v != self[keyPath: attr] {
            self[keyPath: attr] = v
        }
    }

}

myDBObject.importStringAttribute(json, "someAttr", \.someAttr)
```

---

To your question about making this generic over types, that's very straightforward (I just added `<Obj: AnyObject>` and changed the references to "db" to "obj"):

```
func importStringAttribute<Obj: AnyObject>(_ json: JSON, _ key: String, obj: Obj,
                           attr: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Obj, String?>) {
    if !json[key].exists() {
        return
    }
    if let v = json[key].string, v != obj[keyPath: attr] {
        obj[keyPath: attr] = v
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks promising, but i struggle to generalize (parametrize) this across all DB classes :/

Comment: That's a perfect use of generics (and possibly a small protocol). If you have an example of how you're struggling, let me know and I'll show how to do that. (Answer updated with what you might be thinking of.)

Comment: thanks for the edit... i had issue in ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T.Type, String?> (T.Type vs T)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be also to move the set into a block

Before

```
importStringAttribute(json, "someAttr", &myDBObject.someAttr)
```

After

```
importStringAttribute(json, "someAttr", myDBObject.someAttr) { myDBObject.someAttr = $0}
```

code

```
func importStringAttribute(_ json: JSON, _ key: String, _ attr: String?, set:(_ value: String?)->()) {
    if !json[key].exists() {
        return
    }
    if let v = json[key].string, v != attr {
        set(v)
    }
}
```