# Swift array address is not same as &array[0]

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

[Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management/calling_functions_with_pointer_parameters) said:

- An in-out expression that contains a mutable variable, property, or subscript reference of type Type, which is passed as a pointer to the address of the left-hand side identifier.
- A `[Type]` value, which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array.

But when I run the following code :

```swift
func print<Type>(unsafePointer pointer: UnsafePointer<Type>) {
    print("\(pointer) ==> \(pointer.pointee) : \(Type.self)")
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(unsafePointer: array)
print(unsafePointer: &array[0])
```

I get

```
0x0000000104204240 ==> 1 : Int
0x00007ffeefbff440 ==> 1 : Int
```

Why their addresses are different?

Comment: Passing an inout parameter makes a temporary copy, compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32975169/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/31232579/1187415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
print(unsafePointer: array)
```

a pointer to the first element of the array storage is passed to the function. And here

```
print(unsafePointer: &array[0])
```

the subscript operator is called on the array (returning an `Int`) and the address of that (temporary) integer is passed to the function, not the address where the original array element is stored.

That becomes more obvious if you call the functions twice:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print(unsafePointer: array)     // 0x00007ffeefbff2e0
print(unsafePointer: array)     // 0x00007ffeefbff2e0, same as previous address

print(unsafePointer: &array[0]) // 0x00007ffeefbff320
print(unsafePointer: &array[0]) // 0x00007ffeefbff340, different from previous address
```

In addition, passing an in-out expression to a function *can* make a temporary copy, see for example [Swift: always copies on inout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974927/swift-always-copies-on-inout).

Answer (score -2):

Arrays in Swift have value semantics, not the reference semantics of arrays in C or Objective-C. The reason you're seeing different addresses (and addresses at all) is that every time you pass the array as a parameter, you're actually telling Swift to bridge your Array struct to an instance of NSArray.

Comment: Array is bridged to NSArray if you pass it to an Objective-C function taking an NSArray parameter. But that is not what is happening here.